# Mithriljs m.request.then is not a function

Tags: promise, request, mithril.js

I'm trying to write a simple app in Mithril that fetches some data from a remote API but my `m.request` doesn't seem to be returning a promise.

Here's my basic code - the API call is made `oninit` and inspecting the network tab it returns a `200`, but my `.then` is returning an error (I've tried it without the `extract` option too):

```
const Rumour = {
  text: 'Consulting reliable sources...',
  fetch: function () {
    return m.request({
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'https://xxx.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/beta/rumour',
      extract: function(xhr) {return {status: xhr.status, body: xhr.responseText}}
    })
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log(response.body)
    })
    .catch(function (e) {
      console.log(e.message)
    })
  }
}

module.exports = {
  oninit: Rumour.fetch,
  view: function () {
    return m('div.rumour-flex-container', [
      m('p.rumour-element', { id: 'rumour' }, Rumour.text),
      m('button.rumour-element', { onclick: Rumour.fetch }, 'Next Rumour')
    ])
  }
}
```

On the page load the API call is made but in the console I get

`Uncaught TypeError: m.request(...).then0 is not a function`

I've even tried pasting in the example from the [Simple Application](https://mithril.js.org/simple-application.html) in the docs and I get the same error. What am I doing wrong?

In case it's relevant, I'm using the Mithril bundler rather than Webpack as I have no other dependencies and that's apparently not ready for production, but I'm hoping it's a simple mistake I've made somewhere.

Comment: Nothing overtly wrong in what you have posted, `m.request()` should be thenable. Would have to guess that either `m` is not Mithril or it is some ancient version. First thing to try is to make all javascript 'use strict' to ensure that outer members are not inadvertently overwritten.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 thanks - I tried latest and latest stable versions of Mithril and 'use strict' to no avail, anything else you can think of?

Comment: Problem solved! Switched to Webpack and Babel rather than using the Mithril bundler, guess it doesn't polyfill promises

Comment: You must have been running some antique engine for it not to include Promises. Well tracked down.

Comment: The example requires a Bundler like Webpack. Therefore, your code cannot locate Mithril. You could try to include Mithril from CDN

Try including the line:

<script src="https://unpkg.com/mithril/mithril.js"></script>